# Which type of software companies are better for gaining technical experience?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, job-change, software-development

The company that I am currently working for is developing/maintaining a single software product for the last 8~ years. Since I cannot feel the challenge any more, I have been thinking about looking for another job. I need to clarify some questions like this:

Is it better if the company has different customers with different projects; so that you have different subjects and challenges?

Or is it better if it's a company like the one I am working for; because the product is used by many customers and it focuses deeper on specific subjects?

***(Added after some comments on the question):***

I think what I seek is experience about software architecture and using different tools.

Comment: More technical experience.

Comment: What technical experience?   You are are going to get different technical experience working for game company versus database.

Comment: I think what I seek is experience about software architecture and using different tools.

Comment: There is no simple answer; it depends on the specific company and often the specific project. VTC as Opinion

Comment: This might just need some re-wording, but there is a generic trend in software that maintaining code in an environment that isn't updating is causing many people headaches when they move on. Whether it's databases, devops, languages, testing--the question applies to almost anyone in tech.

Comment: Instead of asking "what type of company", maybe you really should ask "what questions can I ask of a potential new job to ensure that..." and then fill in with the things that are important to you. I think there are some questions here along this line that you can find. Basically you want to think of what is important to you and find ways to discover them before taking a new job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a generic answer. Software is changing rapidly, and if  you plan on having a career 5 to 10 years from now your best bet is to get somewhere where you can touch new tools and new development processes.  If your company is allowing you to do that, it's fine to stay there. But if you're continuing to babysit code that is older, then you will have less marketable skills when eventually something disrupts their niche and you need to move on.

Your intuitions are likely correct, and it's time to go now.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question of what kind of company to seek...?

Comment: @keshlam Seek a company that uses new tools.